# MySQL: Select IP from table with ip ranges

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a SELECT query.

There is a table 'cities', which maps IP ranges to cities.

```
ip_from  ip_to          city
------------------------------------
0.0.0.0  0.255.255.255  Los Angeles
1.0.0.0  1.0.0.255      South Brisbane
1.0.1.0  1.0.3.255      Fuzhou
1.0.4.0  1.0.7.255      Ripponlea
1.0.8.0  1.0.15.255     Guangzhou
```

Example: IP 0.1.2.3 would be 'Los Angeles' and 1.0.8.255 'Guangzhou'.

Now I would like to get the cities with fixed IP addresses like that:

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE ip IN ('0.1.2.3', '1.0.8.255')
```

which should deliver the aforementioned cities 'LA' and 'Guangzhou'.

Is this possible? Would that be performant, because this table has about 5 mio entries?

Thanks,
Bernhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You can try something like :</s>

```
SELECT city
FROM cities
WHERE (INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN INET_ATON('0.1.2.3') AND INET_ATON('1.0.8.255'));
```

**EDIT** : Tested, it works !

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE (INET_ATON('0.0.0.0') BETWEEN INET_ATON(ip_from) AND INET_ATON(ip_to));
```

Where `0.0.0.0` is the IP that you want to test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's not quite what I needed.
So if I want to know which city has the IP '1.0.8.255', I would have to iterate through the 'ip_from' and the 'ip_to' columns. The first match would be the city 'Guangzhou', because ip_from  is >1.0.8.0 and ip_to is <1.0.15.255 .

Comment: That is what I understood. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Okay, it's better now ! It's a lot more complicated ! Let me think about it :)

Comment: Untested but may work : `SELECT city
FROM cities
WHERE (INET_ATON('0.0.0.0') BETWEEN INET_ATON(ip_from) AND INET_ATON(ip_to));` Where `0.0.0.0` is the IP that you want to test.